# HTML/CSS Background Image doesn't display

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to set a background image for my page, but when I set it using CSS it doesn't show up and my BG remains blank. 
This is my CSS code:

```
body {
background-image: url("Images/bg.png");
}

hr {
margin-left: 12%;
margin-right: 12%;
color: #000000;
background-color: #000000;
height: 3px;
}

h1 {
text-align: center ;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 300%;
}

h3 {
text-align: left ;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 150%;
}

#menu {
text-align: center;
}

.titles {
margin-left: 12%;
margin-right: 12%;
}

p {
text-align: justify ;
font-family: Verdana;
margin-right: 12%; 
margin-left: 12%; 
}
```

And this is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Homepagina Olympische Spelen" />
<meta name="keywords" content="welkom, homepagina, olympische spelen, olympic games, sporten" /> 

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 

<link href="styles/eersteStijl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Olympische Zomerspelen</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Olympische Spelen</h1>

<div id="menu">
<a href="index.html"><img
src="images/buttons/home_btn.png"
alt=""
onmouseover="this.src='Images/buttons/home_btn_rollover.png';"
onmouseout="this.src='Images/buttons/home_btn.png';"
/></a>

<a href="info.html"><img
src="images/buttons/info_btn.png"
alt=""
onmouseover="this.src='Images/buttons/info_btn_rollover.png';"
onmouseout="this.src='Images/buttons/info_btn.png';"
/></a>

<a href="contact.html"><img
src="images/buttons/contact_btn.png"
alt=""
onmouseover="this.src='Images/buttons/contact_btn_rollover.png';"
onmouseout="this.src='Images/buttons/contact_btn.png';"
/></a>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="titles"><h3>Welkom</h3></div>
<p>
[Some text here]

<p>
<video width="320" height="240" poster="images/video_start.jpg">
<source src="Images/olympic_games_promo.mp4" /> 
<source src="Images/olympic_games_promo.webm" />
Uw browser ondersteunt geen video.
</video>
</p>

<div class="titles"><h3>Olympische Spelen</h3></div>
<p>
[More text]
</p>

<div class="titles"><h3>Amateurs en beroepsporten</h3></div>
<p>
[And more text] 
</p>

<p>
<img src="Images/olympisch_stadion.jpg" alt="Olympisch Stadion" /> <br> 
<i>Olympisch Stadion in Athene</i>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything from the CSS works except the BG image, anybody got an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When posting a question on SO, please try to cut down your code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem first.

Comment: @hon2a ironically in this instance, having all of it helped identify that the style sheet and the images were in a separate folder. Sometimes you cannot identify what the minimum required is!

Comment: That is IMO incorrect. You can always try to cut down parts of the code and see if the issue persists. In this particular case, it'd leave the OP with just an empty body and a single CSS rule.

Comment: With an empty body though, it wouldn't have been obvious that he stores his images in an "images" folder in the root. Much better to have too much than not enough! The number of times we get people that don't post anything is ridiculous, so for a first-time poster to give us something helpful to identify the problem is actually rather good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path is wrong. Your style sheet is in the Styles folder.

You need "/Images/bg.png" to go to the root

Comment: Don't forget to click the tick for the answer that helps solve your problem

Comment: Sorry I'm new, but I ticked your answer!

Comment: Don't worry about it, it takes a while for all the Stack Overflow protocols to get into your blood stream ;)